# Set-Step is not recognised in Powershell script i am using

Tags: powershell, path, powershell-cmdlet, spelling

Set-Step : The term 'Set-Step' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The above is the error i am facing while running PowerShell script to generate report from grabbing data from source.
Please help me to solve this issue .

Comment: That is not a command. Someone might have written one for you, but in that case you would need to import or dot-source it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with Set-Step?  As @tonypags wrote it is not a command and could have been a module someone wrote to do something.

Comment: $sdate = [datetime]"6/24/2022"
### DON'T CHANGE BELOW
# This prevents errors due to errant keystrokes
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# include global functions and startup routine
 ..\..\Global\Production\Globals.ps1
#Import-Module sqlserver

$now = [datetime]::Now

$lastitemProcessed = $null
$err = $null

    $step = Set-Step "Exporting sql reports"
    $exportPath = "$($globals.FeedsDrop_BasePath)\feeds_drop_sql" #"\\samssp0064\feeds_drop_sql"
    $recordsPerBatch = 50000 . This is the code written to export the data from the path to other.

Comment: I got this issue resolved .some member in my team accidentally removed a (.) from the script while calling Global.ps1. Thank you for your time